# Is there any privacy- or security-relevant difference between FIDO2 and SQRL

Tags: authentication, privacy, identity, fido2, sqrl

I just learned about [FIDO2 (WebAuthn)](https://fidoalliance.org/fido2/fido2-web-authentication-webauthn/) and try to make a **comparison** to the lesser-known novel [SQRL](https://www.grc.com/sqrl/sqrl.htm) authentication scheme.

Both seem to use the same key elements:

- a private, user-resident "master key" thus not relying on a 3rd party like OAuth.
- a specific piece of soft- or hardware managing the identity
- a specific protocol to establish/claim an identity to a web server/service
- an intermediate public key, derived from the master key
- the intermediate public key is unique to a domain name, thus providing privacy against other servers/services on other domains
- a changing challenge/nonce for each authentication attempt, to mitigate against replay attacks.

**So, with this, is there a significant difference I did not spot yet?**

Note: This is not about usability or specific implementations of it (clients or server components, but more about the architecture.

---

Resources for FIDO2

- https://fidoalliance.org/fido2/fido2-web-authentication-webauthn/
- https://fidoalliance.org/specs/fido-uaf-v1.1-ps-20170202/fido-uaf-overview-v1.1-ps-20170202.pdf (Spec)
- https://www.heise.de/select/ct/2019/18/1566919516550023

Resources for SQRL

- https://sqrl.pl/guide/ (Illustrated Guide)
- https://www.grc.com/sqrl/sqrl.htm
- https://sqrl.pl/blog/

Answer (score 1):

The most different part between the two seems to be how identities for websites are created:

- SQRL derives identities for all websites from the master key
- FIDO creates and stores a random identity for each website

This means, that [SQRL](https://www.grc.com/sqrl/sqrl.htm) tightly binds a user identity to a website. See [SQRL's Identity Lock Protocol](https://www.grc.com/sqrl/idlock.htm). However, the concept of alternate identities is provided.

Also, the [Transcript of Security now Episode #875](https://www.grc.com/sn/sn-875.htm) contains some comparative sections. Disclaimer: SQRL was createdy by Steve Gibson, which is also the host of the Security Now podcast.